# How can I copy all visible text of a webView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `webView` that loads a page. How do I copy all visible text on the `webView`? I **don't** want the `innerHTML`. I want the visible text. In other words, I want the same text that can be achieved by "selecting all" and copying.

Comment: you got any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Use a HTML parser which can give you nodes under your body element and keep aggregating text present inside each node. You could use this https://jsoup.org/
as a parser, it is quite established.

Comment: probably there is but this answer is not written to give you the code.